# Angular routerLink navigating to wrong path on 'nested' pages

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm building a basic notes app in Angular 12 where the notes are stored in Firebase. Notes contain text but can also act as a parent node for more notes, e.g:

```
Note
Note
|- Note
  |- Note
  |- Note
    |- Note
|- Note
Note
```

You can view a list of a note's child notes from `/notes/{{note.id}}` and edit the note itself at `/edit/{{note.id}}`. If the id for `/notes/` is null, it grabs all of the top level notes.

**The problem:** Everything works fine until I try to view the notes list of the second level of the hierarchy. The routerLink appears to add both `/edit/{{note.id}}` and `/notes/{{note.id}}` to the navigation stack, e.g:

```
Note1
|- Note2 <-- click '>' button on note2 in list view
  |- Note3 <-- expect to see note3 in list view
```

Instead of viewing `notes/2`, instead I'm taken to `edit/2`. Clicking back in the browser takes me to the proper route I wanted of `notes/2`, allowing me to see note3 in the list view. Why would `/edit/{{note.id}}` be added to the router when you click the icon button?

**EDIT: StackBlitz link to demo the issue here:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcmvab

Relevant code snippets below:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'notes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'notes',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: NotesComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: NotesComponent },
    ],
  },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: NoteDetailsComponent }
];
```

**notes.component.ts**

```js
export class NotesComponent implements OnInit {
  parentID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  notes: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private notesService: NotesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveNotes();
  }

  retrieveNotes(): void {
    this.notesService
      .getChildNotes(this.parentID)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((changes: any) =>
          changes.map((c: any) => ({
            id: c.payload.doc.id,
            ...c.payload.doc.data(),
          }))
        )
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.notes = data;
      });
  }
}
```

**notes.component.html**

```html
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let note of notes" [routerLink]="['/edit', note.id]">
    <mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined" mat-list-icon>description_outlined</mat-icon>
    <div mat-line>{{note?.title}}</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="note.children.length > 0" [routerLink]="['/notes', note.id]">
      <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a route with a variable number of parameters. Something like `/note/a/b/c/d/e`. One way to achieve that is to use a route with a custom url matcher, that accepts the route if it begins with `/note` (or your prefix of choice) and collects all the rest of the segments and passes them to the component.

Here's how the route would be defined:

```js
const variableRouteMatcher: UrlMatcher = (
  segments: UrlSegment[]
): UrlMatchResult => {
  if (segments.length >= 1 && segments[0].path === 'note') {
    const fullPath = segments
      .slice(1)
      .map(r => r.path)
      .join('/');
    return {
      consumed: segments,
      posParams: {
        fullPath: new UrlSegment(fullPath, {})
      }
    };
  }
  return null;
};

const routes: Routes = [
  { matcher: variableRouteMatcher, component: NoteComponent }
];
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7sgooa?file=src/app/app.module.ts) example

**EDIT (based on comment)** After looking at your stackblitz, I've seen two problems, one as Cantarzo pointed in his answer, the fact that there is a link element inside another link element.

But the more critical error is that your `notes` component doesn't listen to changes in its route parameters, it takes a snapshot of the route and then uses that forever. Remember that Angular reuses components in routes, so the very same `NoteComponent` instance is used whenever you navigate to a note.

This means that the first time you navigate into a note, it gets its parent id, and then regardless of where you go, the parent id stays the same.

To solve this, you have to *subscribe* to changes in the activated route's parameters and update your parent id (and also your child notes) accordingly

See your [forked stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjhmj5?file=src/app/notes/notes.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and example, but this seems like overkill for my needs. Every note has a unique id and its content can be viewed by /edit/id and any child notes viewed through /notes/id no matter how deeply nested. From the Angular docs, specifying a routerLink of ['/'] ought to reference the root URL of my app but it doesn't after the first child. Here is a StackBlitz to highlight the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcmvab

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer - this fixed it for me! I feel a bit foolish for not seeing that I'd snapshotted the parameter. I will also ensure (as per the other answer) to separate the links. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're putting one `[routerLink]` inside another.
You should move the `[routerLink]` attribute from `<mat-list-item>` to another place, like a button inside of it. The way you're doing it is probably activating first the button click and then the click at the whole list item.

Try to change to this:

```js
     <mat-list-item *ngFor="let note of notes" >
        <mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined" mat-list-icon>description_outlined</mat-icon>
        <div mat-line>{{note?.title}}</div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <button mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['/notes', note.id]">
          <mat-icon>Some-Edit-Icon</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="note.children.length > 0" [routerLink]="['/notes', note.id]">
          <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

Than just adjust the way you like.
Another problem you may have is that you're passing the `notes.id` to the `[routerLink]` that access the children note. Maybe you should put a `*ngFor` and pass `children.id` instead

If this solution does not work, please create a stackBlitz so we can see the problem more clearly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have tried this but the behaviour persists. I have quickly thrown together this StackBlitz if it helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcmvab. The aim is to make it seem like a mobile app with infinitely nested notes.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I accepted the other answer as that solved the root issue (no pun intended) of snapshotting the parameter, but your advice to split out the links has also been taken on board.